# How can I count how many markers on Google Map V2

Tags: android, marker

I want to count how many markers on google map v2 on android. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too general.
How do you load your markers in the google map?

You can use the function getMarkerCount, that is explained in detail at this link:
http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markermanager/1.1/docs/reference.html